# Equal spaces between CSS border dots?

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS code which creates a simple dotted border here:

```
border: 5px dotted #ff2100
```

Now the problem is at the very top where those two last dots are too close to each other...

[image]

What if I want equal spaces between all of the dots... Please help...

Edit: I need it only on chrome and Here is the whole CSS (`border: 5px dotted #ff2100` is at the very end...)

```
html {
overflow: hidden; 
  width: 1470px;
  height: 450px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  flex: 50%;
}

.profile {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 100px 70px 0px 0px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color:#161b7a;
}

.profile .name {

  margin-right: -260px;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-weight: 600;
  src: url(helveticaneue-ultrathin.woff);
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.profile .job {


  margin-right: -260px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #b69cd1;
  src: url(helveticaneue-ultrathin.woff);
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}


.profile .count {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 60px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: url(helveticaneue-ultrathin.woff);
  color: #E6E0EC;
  font-size: 21px;
  min-width: 76px;
}

.profile img.profilePic {
  position: absolute;
  margin: -50px 70px 50px 50px;
  background: #2f293d;
  border: 4px solid #2f293d;
  padding: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: .2rem .2rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.profile img.profileDia {
  position: absolute;
  margin: -7px 70px 50px 560px;
  width: 2.3%;
  height: auto;
}




.points {
  position: absolute;
  margin: -2px 100px 100px 490px;
  float: right;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  font-weight: 800;
  src: url(helveticaneue-ultrathin.woff);
  color: #0047ba;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.level {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 25px 100px 100px 135px;
  float: right;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-weight: 800;
  src: url(helveticaneue-ultrathin.woff);
  color: #ed0909;
  font-size: 20px;

  display: block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;

    -moz-border-radius: 30px; /* or 50% */
    border-radius: 30px; /* or 50% */

    background-color: #2c094f;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}



.profile img.profilePic.custom-borderA {
   border: 5px dotted #ff2100

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="profiles"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="profiles"></div>
  </div>
</div>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
<script src="Script.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have never had this issue. did you use `box-sizing: border-box;` as a preset?

Comment: @AnduAndrici I tried but it's not worked !

Comment: I made [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/q8cvL7t4/1/) for you, but I don't think there's a solution. The result looks different in different browsers.

Comment: I've added the code...

Comment: I need it only on chrome ...

Comment: @ Saravana Javascript.

Comment: under which class? adding as `background-image`?

Comment: .profile img.profilePic

Comment: Would you like to take a look at it on codepen?

Comment: there is no class `(.profile img.profilePic)` in html update in codepen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192203/discussion-between-saravana-and-sara-ree).

Comment: @Saravana there is no way... here is w3.org note: There is no control over the spacing of the dots and dashes, nor over the length of the dashes. Implementations are encouraged to choose a spacing that makes the corners symmetrical.

Comment: @SaraRee okay noted.

Comment: instead of `border`, use `gradient`. I had this issue and its solved now using gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't fix this issue with pure css [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#the-border-style). You can use a background image or a border-image that does the trick.

Comment: Even no way to modifying the space between dots?!

Comment: according to my research, no way!

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: this solution seems to work only under some circumstances (OS, Chrome version etc). Use at your own peril.*

---

What you need to do is to round the number of red dots to a whole number.

With a 150x150 picture, the circumference is 486.95 pixels, which cannot fit a whole number of 5px dots. One solution would have been to use 4.9688px for a border-width, but that won't work; the browser rounds the border width to an integer.
So we'll have to resort to a little trickery to make it fit. We'll make the image bigger, give it a border width in whole pixels and then scale the whole thing down to its original size.

I'm sorry I can't use your source, since your source doesn't contain the image, but I hope you can work with this.

```css
.profile {
  width:160px; height:160px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.profile img {
  vertical-align:top;
  background:#2F293D;
  /* multiply the size by 32 */
  width:calc(150px * 32); height:calc(150px * 32);
  border:calc((5px * 32) - 1px) dotted #FF2100;
  border-radius:50%;
  /* then scale back by the same factor */
  transform:scale(calc(1 / 32));
  transform-origin:0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile">
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2IqJ.jpg" alt="photo">
</div>
```

For comparison, here is a snippet without the trickery, that demonstrates the uneven positioning of the dots.

```css
.profile {
  width:160px; height:160px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.profile img {
  vertical-align:top;
  background:#2F293D;
  border:5px dotted #FF2100;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile">
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2IqJ.jpg" alt="photo">
</div>
```

Note that I had to put a container around the image with `overflow:hidden`, otherwise the browser would still think the image was as large as its `width` and `height` and would reserve space accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Mr Lister for the answer... Still, I can't make your code work on my own code... both snippets you've provided seems to have that the uneven positioning of the dots.

Comment: Hm, I have it working on my machine, but it does appear other OS and/or Chrome versions handle this differently. Sorry about that. I should have tested better.

Comment: No problem...when CSS can't do simple things... plus one for chiming in...

Answer (score 2):

One solution to your problem would be to use "Border-image". Using this css property you can apply a border-image rather than the border direct and would get rid of the problem of mixing dots. 
For details you can refer "https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/".